# Is there anything like "recent mode" in Outlook.com?

Tags: outlook.com, pop3

Gmail has a feature called "recent mode" for its POP access: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/47948

Does Outlook.com have a feature like that?

Comment: Hotmail has been discontinued. Do you mean outlook.com?

Comment: @AlEverett yes.